# How to completely abort a Haskell runtime?

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
import System.Exit

exit_and_report_type_mismatch :: String -> IO ExitCode
exit_and_report_type_mismatch error_message = do
    putStrLn error_message
    exitFailure
```

and a section of another like so

```
interpret_expr :: Vars -> Expr -> Val        
interpret_expr vars (Plus (ConsE _ _) (NumE _)) = exit_and_report_type_mismatch "Type Error: Can only concatenate list (not int) to list"
```

Haskell complains to me that it is expecting type Val (another data type I have defined) but it actually receives type IO Exitcode. Fair enough - exit_and_report_mismatch is returning IO ExitCode which is not a Val.

How do I completely abort the Haskell program from within "exit_and_report_type_mismatch"? I have read a bit about Haskell exceptions but the explanations either do not make sense or mention having to call ExitWith from the main function, which is not an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what [`error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aerror) is for.  From the documentation:

> `error :: [Char] -> a`
>   [`error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aerror) stops execution and displays an error message.

For instance:

```
zsh% runhaskell <<<'main = putStrLn (error "Message") >> print "Not reached."'
runghcXXXX7729.hs: Message
```

The effect of `putStrLn` is ignored, and the program terminates as soon as the value produced by `error` is demanded (lazy evaluation means that just putting `error` somewhere doesn't immediately cause an error; as you might or might not expect, `let x = error "Message" in putStrLn "Printed"` causes no errors).  It *is* possible to catch these exceptions with the functions from [`Control.Exception.Base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html), such as [`catch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v%3acatch), but I've never done this nor have I seen this done.

Also, as a final note, consider avoiding the use of `error`.  Partial functions (functions that aren't defined over their entire input domain) are best avoided when possible, as it's much easier to reason about your code with the stronger guarantees total functions provide.  It's nice when, as for total functions, `f :: A -> B` really means "the function `f` returns something of type `B`"; for partial functions, `f :: A -> B` means only "*if the function `f` returns*, then what it returns is of type `B`".  In your case, this might mean having a type like `interpretExpr :: Vars -> Expr -> Either RuntimeError Val`, or something suitably isomorphic (in the simplest case, perhaps `data Result = Error String | Value Val`, and `interpretExpr :: Vars -> Expr -> Result`).

Comment: also consider using [`undefined`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:undefined), which is sometimes more appropriate for readability. but both should only be used to flag programmer errors, not user errors.

Comment: @Antal S-Z thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for your final note too. I'm not sure what you mean by partial types, as using error in my function has not led to Haskell complaining about type errors?

Comment: @nebffa: Partial functions aren't about partial types—almost the opposite, in some ways :-) Consider `head :: [a] -> a`.  It's well-typed, of course; however, sometimes, it doesn't actually return, but crashes instead. This is what makes `head` partial that `head []` isn't a value. This is so *even though* `head []` is well-typed; this is what I meant by "almost the opposite". If a function `f` is total (like `fst :: (a,b) -> a`), then `f x` is guaranteed to produce a value for all `x`. (I'm ignoring infinite and partial data, like `[1..]` and `undefined`, but this is the basic idea.)

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

exit_and_report_type_mismatch :: String -> a
exit_and_report_type_mismatch error_message = unsafePerformIO $ do
    putStrLn error_message
    exitFailure
```

The function [error](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:error) might work the same though.